# How do we identify if app is launched via app banners?

Tags: swift, ios9, deep-linking, smartbanner

How do we identify if app is launched via app banners?

When app banner is tapped it calls delegate method -

func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool

But there can be other instances when this method could be invoked. How can we be 100% sure if app banner is tapped and nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide context to the app banner via its *app-argument* parameter. See [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).

For example:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myscheme://settings">
```

The URL you would receive in `- application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` is `myscheme://settings`.

Comment: We are calling open url method from other places in the code which has the scheme same as in smart banner implementation.

Comment: If the scheme and path are shared and also used in other places, the easiest solution in my opinion would be to append a parameter to the `app-argument`, for example `myscheme://settings?app_banner=1`. You can then check for the parameter in the delegate method.